# C# PowerPoint Interop: Get default text of a placeholder textbox

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop

Does anyone know a way to get the default text of a placeholder shape in powerpoint?

I defined a placeholder text shape in the master with default text ("Enter some text here ...").
[image: Placeholder default text]

The text can be overwritten in the slide of the presentation.
[image: Placeholder set text]

I want to get the text "Enter some text here ..." by code!!!
Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the VBA to do the job.  Language translation left as an exercise for the astute reader:

```
Dim osh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oLyt As CustomLayout
Dim x As Long ' VBA Long, not a .NET Long!

' for demo purposes, we'll work with a placeholder shape
' that I've selected
Set osh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
' and in Real Life, you'd want to ensure that the
' shape really is a placeholder of the correct type

Set oSl = osh.Parent
Set oLyt = oSl.CustomLayout

For x = 1 To oLyt.Shapes.Count
    If oLyt.Shapes(x).PlaceholderFormat.Type = osh.PlaceholderFormat.Type Then
        Debug.Print oLyt.Shapes(x).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    End If
Next
```

This isn't perfect; it just takes you to the first placeholder on the layout that's of the same placeholder type as the shape you're working with.  You might have multiple placeholders on the same slide and its corresponding layout, in which case this could give you incorrect results.  If you want to guard against that, you might want to test whether there are other placeholders of the same type on the parent slide and if this is the Nth placeholder, determine the value for N, then find the Nth matching placeholder on the layout.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Unfortunatly it is the opposite direction as I need it. My goal was to get a reference from placeholder in layout to the according placeholder textbox on the slide. Because there's no "native way", my idea was to get it by placeholder default text. But this seems to be impossible too. Cant understand why microsoft doesn't offer any possibilities to get a reference between the layout placeholder and the textbox on the slide. :-(

Comment: The same general strategy would work for this.  But let me ask what the goal is.

Comment: I have a layout with placeholders defined in the master and need the according textbox of the slide based on the layout, because i have to validate this one.